# Halftone effect in with gdi+

Tags: c#, gdi+

How would I go about mimicking [this](http://www.juicybitssoftware.com/halftone/) halftone effect in GDI+?

It almost looks like [Floyd–Steinberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering) dithered version of the image overlaying a full one but I'm not convinced.

[image]

Comment: It's not halftone, the pixel size isn't variable.  It is a patterned dither.  Printing press algorithms are secretive.

Comment: @HansPassant: Hmmm... Ok then. Fingers crossed someone will spread the love.

Comment: Hmm, why don't you just implement it?  There's nothing built-in that will make it easy.  Zoom into the image to see the pattern.

Comment: If I could I wouldn't be asking a question about how I would go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gave this a try and got this result:
[image]

It may be a place to start. I did it like this:

1. Draw the original picture with low saturation (using a color
   matrix)
2. Draw the original image onto 1) with high saturation
   using a pattern mask (ie the dots)

I created the pattern mask like this:

```
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpPattern))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Black);
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            for (var y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y += 10)
                for (var x = 0; x < bmp.Width ; x += 6)
                {
                    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, x, y, 4, 4);
                    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, x + 3, y + 5, 4, 4);
                }
        }
```

And then I imposed it over the oversaturated bitmap using [this technique](http://danbystrom.se/2008/08/24/soft-edged-images-in-gdi/).

**Update**: Elaboration on how the images got merged. Let's talk even a little more general and say that we want to combine two different colorized versions of the same image using a pattern mask, resulting in a new image - we could do it like this:

Create THREE new bitmaps, all with the same size as the original image. Call them bmpA, bmpB and bmpMask.

- Draw one colored/effect version into bmpA
- Draw the other colored/effect version into bmpB
- Create the mask in bmpMask (black and white)
- Push one of the R/G/B channels of bmpMask into the alpha channel of bmpB using the
  transferOneARGBChannelFromOneBitmapToAnother method.
- Draw bmpB over bmpA (since bmpB now has transparent parts in it)
- The result is now bmpA. bmpB and bmpMask can be disposed.

Done

Comment: Cheers for that. The effect is nice and looks like something I could work with. I've noticed in your example code in your blog the method `code`transferOneARGBChannelFromOneBitmapToAnother used unsafe code. This stuff is mostly for web development so medium trust is a must for me. Do you have an example of the method that wouldn't utilize unsafe code?

Comment: It is pretty simple to change. Here is code that moves the bitmap bytes out to an ordinary byte[] and then back again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: And here is how you change saturation: http://www.bobpowell.net/imagesaturation.htm . Brightness and contrast can also be achived using a color matrix.

Comment: You don't happen to still have the app that you wrote to test this do you? I'm revisiting it and I'm getting lost.

Comment: Sorry, no. Not where I can find it without trouble. But if you have any code to share I can try to guide you.

Comment: Absolutely!.. Here's a [link](http://sdrv.ms/MQA8mr) I _think_ I have rewritten your unsafe code I'm actually lost on this section of your instructions:

1. Draw the original picture with low saturation (using a color matrix)
2. Draw the original image onto 1) with high saturation using a pattern mask (ie the dots)

Thanks so much for this!

Comment: Looked at you code. I have updated my answer above to be a little more verbose. Hope that helps!

Comment: Cheers for that. much clearer now. I've managed to replicate the effect and it looks good! :-)